# Returning 3 Values to post based linked radio Butten

Tags: vba

I have Created 3 Radio Buttons Card, Cash, EFT, but the script I write no matter  what i use populates an error I know IIF only returns two values but else does not work aswell.

The issue is here Below

.Range("G" & iRow).Value = IIf(optCard.Value = True, "Card", "EFT")
 based on the above I need to add a 3rd selection for the two it works fine but what ever i add after seems to be meet with errors
Please Help

Please see the script below.

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim iRow As Long

iRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If ValidateForm = True Then

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

       .Range("A" & iRow).Value = iRow - 1
       .Range("D" & iRow).Value = txtValue.Value
       .Range("G" & iRow).Value = IIf(optCard.Value = True, "Card", "EFT")
       .Range("B" & iRow).Value = cmbAccount.Text
       .Range("E" & iRow).Value = txtWeek.Value
       .Range("F" & iRow).Value = txtRetailer.Value
       .Range("H" & iRow).Value = txtDate.Value

    End With
    Call Reset
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Just to clarify you want to write either "Card", "Cash" or "EFT" to the Cell Gx depending on the value of optCard.Value? (What is optCard anyway? Is it a userForm that you called earlier?)

Comment: I Came Right I noticed That IIf Would work, its just how you structure it the solution is as per the below,

Comment: .Range("G" & iRow).Value = IIf(optCard.Value = True, "Card", IIf(optCash.Value = True, "Cash", IIf(optDebitOrder.Value = True, "Debit Order", "EFT")))

Comment: I also managed to add a forth Selection

Comment: But yes its a form, i designed that carried two simple selections through means of a radio button that you would have to select, but thank you for taking interest, much appreciated.